# Jquery ajax call not working properly

Tags: jquery

I use following code doing ajax call for update page. but it only work for 1st time, if I try second time it reload. if I try an another time it works. do you have any idea? what is the wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href*='delete']").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        url = 'http://localhost'+url;

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : url,
            success : function(data){
                $('#table_div').html($(data).find('#table_div'));
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked your browsers console for Javascript-errors? Edit: you might also use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop the bubbling of the click-event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("a[href*='delete']").on('click', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    url = 'http://localhost'+url;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('#table_div').html($(data).find('#table_div'));
    })
    .success(function(data) { $('#table_div').html($(data).find('#table_div')); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
});
```

Greetings.